# How to remove useless characters in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataset like below, how can I remove the '#number'?

```
df>
terms                             year
5;#Remote Production;#10;         2021
53;#=Product-Category:Routing     2021
30;#HDR;#5;#Remote Production     2020
...
```

I need it to be like this:

```
df>
terms                          year
#Remote Production             2021
#Product-Category:Routing      2021
#HDR;#Remote Production     2020
...
```

The number at the beginning without the # also needs to be removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option with `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(terms = str_c('#', str_remove_all(terms, "^\\d+;#\\=?|#\\d+;")))
```

-output

```
#                     terms year
#1       #Remote Production; 2021
#2 #Product-Category:Routing 2021
#3   #HDR;#Remote Production 2020
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(terms = c("5;#Remote Production;#10;", "53;#=Product-Category:Routing", 
"30;#HDR;#5;#Remote Production"), year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2020L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: why you use the str_c function?

Comment: @kvjing because it was removing the `#` so, I reinserted that by pasting using `str_c` at the beginning

Comment: It gives an error: 
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"df %>%
  mutate(terms="

Comment: should I run this piece of code first?
df <- structure(list(terms = c("5;#Remote Production;#10;", "53;#=Product-Category:Routing", 
"30;#HDR;#5;#Remote Production"), year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2020L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

Comment: @kvjing have you loaded the library i.e. `library(dplyr)`

Comment: @kvjing it works for me - updated the output I got

Comment: @kvjing I am not getting the error.  The `data` showed in my post is to show a reproducible example.  You can get that structure from `dput(yourdata)`, but that is not needed

Comment: ok I get it too. There is another problem: in some entries, the "terms" are empty. after running this code, there is a "#" added, which is not what I want... do you know how to remove it?

Comment: @kvjing Do you have `NA` or `""` for those elements.  If it is `""`, then we can use `df %>% mutate(terms = case_when(terms != "" ~ str_c('#', str_remove_all(terms, "^\\d+;#\\=?|#\\d+;")), TRUE ~ terms))` and if it is `NA` use `!is.na(terms) ~` in `case_when`